# I have a fixed menu. I will like to create a button (with in the menu) that rise up the fixed menu from its position

Tags: html, css

I have seen examples online. Where a user is able to click on a button within a fixed menu, an which rise up the menu. Any thoughts?

here is an example of what I want http://www.marthastewart.com/344840/soft-and-chewy-chocolate-chip-cookies  ( on this site there is a fixed menu in the bottom)

Comment: rise up the menu? Can you explain that more?

Comment: Show us an example of those you have seen. And then show us what you have tried

Comment: **My thoughts on this:** I'm proud that you can search the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with jquery `scrollTop` on a click function

```
$(".header ul li").click(function(){

   var findSection = $(this).attr("class");
   $("html,body").animate({"scrollTop": $(".section-"+findSection).offset().top-60});

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A54NK/1/)

**UPDATE**

I didn't see what part you were talking about specifically when I posted the above but you can do something like this:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A54NK/2/)